# formatter output doesn't appear in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

Can I make my shiny app use the formats applied in formatter?

The first column prints in green when listed, but not in the shiny.

```
ft <- formattable(mtcars,
            list(mpg = formatter("span", style = "color:green")))

#mpg prints green here:
ft

app = shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             formattableOutput('table')

      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    #but not here
    output$table <- renderFormattable({formattable(ft, list())})
      }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function `formattable` twice. Second time in the app with an empty `list()` containing no format options. Basically you are overwiting the format that you defined earlier, with an empty format. To solve this there are two options.

One is to define your table outside the app and render the output without overwriting the format:

```
output$table <- renderFormattable({ft})
```

But it is also possible to define the table and format options inside you server:

```
output$table <- renderFormattable({formattable(mtcars,
                                                   list(mpg = formatter("span", style = "color:green")))})
```